# Proving a function is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there a nice way to prove that $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x-3$ is strictly increasing without making use of derivatives or any other advanced concepts ? I'm trying to explain it to a 9th grader, but I can't find an elegant, clear solution .
Thanks !

Comment: Try explaining it visually by plotting a graph for each of the terms and in total?

Comment: 9th graders aren't acquainted with function plotting, so I'm trying to avoid this method

Comment: $x^2$ isn't strictly increasing

Comment: @Victor Sorry, you're correct comment removed. I was only considering positive $x$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Explain $$f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)((x+y)^2+(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2)/2$$

Comment: Well, obviously $x-y$ is a factor, then we have $x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1$ as the other factor.  Now it is a matter of completing squares. This is simpler once you see it as $\frac12(x^2+2xy+y^2 \;+x^2+2x+1\;+y^2+2y+1)$.